# How to recursively fill an array with functions?

Tags: arrays, matlab, function, recursion

So I'm trying to write a function to generate Hermite polynomials and it's doing something super crazy ... Why does it generate different elements for `h` when I start with a different `n`? So inputting `Hpoly(2,1)` gives

`h = [ 1, 2*y, 4*y^2 - 2]`

while for `Hpoly(3,1)` ,

`h = [ 1, 2*y, 4*y^2 - 4, 2*y*(4*y^2 - 4) - 8*y]`

( (4y^2 - **2**) vs (4y^2 - **4**) as a third element here )

also, I can't figure out how to actually evaluate the expression. I tried `out = subs(h(np1),y,x)` but that did nothing.

code:

```
function out = Hpoly(n, x)
clc;

syms y

    np1 = n + 1;
    h = [1, 2*y];
    f(np1)

    function f(np1)
        if numel(h) < np1
             f(np1 - 1)
             h(np1) = 2*y*h(np1-1) - 2*(n-1)*h(np1-2);
        end
    end
h
y = x;
out = h(np1);

end
```

-------------------------- EDIT ----------------------------

So I got around that by using a `while` loop instead. I wonder why the other way didn't work ... (and still can't figure out how to evaluate the expression other than just plug in x from the very beginning ... I suppose that's not that important, but would still be nice to know...)

Sadly, my code isn't as fast as `hermiteH` :( I wonder why.

```
function out = Hpoly(n, x)

    h = [1, 2*x];
    np1 = n + 1;

    while np1 > length(h)
        h(end+1) = 2*x*h(end) - 2*(length(h)-1)*h(end-1);
    end

out = h(end)

end
```

Comment: Is this an exercise – is there a reason you're not using [`hermiteH`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/hermiteh.html)?

Comment: The computers at school don't have the version of MatLab that has hermiteH function so my code won't work on them :(

Comment: You say " I tried `out = subs(h(np1),y,x)` but that did nothing." What does that mean? Was there an error? what was returned? I assume that `y` was a symbolic variable and `x` was a double?

Comment: i meant the same thing was returned as with `out = h(np1);` in the first code I posted

Comment: Your first code appears like it might be mixing up printing (lines missing ending semicolons) with returned values. `Hpoly1(2,1)` only returns `4*y^2 - 2`, not `[ 1, 2*y, 4*y^2 - 2]`. It can also be a bad idea (confusing) to put `clc` in a utility function like this.

Comment: The first one also returns the whole array `h`. I just had it there for comparison. And yeah, I only use `clc` when I'm troubleshooting to keep the workspace tidy, so it's easier to see the updates :3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why is your code slower? Recursion is not necessarily of Matlab's fortes so you may have improved it by using a [recurrence relation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation). However, [`hermiteH`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/hermiteh.html) is written in C and your loop won't be as fast as it could be because you're using a `while` instead of `for` and needlessly reallocating memory instead of preallocating it. `hermiteH` may even use a lookup table for the first coefficients or it might benefit from vectorization using the [explicit expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermite_polynomials#Explicit_expression). I might rewrite your function like this:

```
function h = Hpoly(n,x)
% n - Increasing sequence of integers starting at zero
% x - Point at which to evaluate polynomial, numeric or symbolic value
mx = max(n);
h = cast(zeros(1,mx),class(x)); % Use zeros(1,mx,'like',x) in newer versions of Matlab
h(1) = 1;
if mx > 0
    h(2) = 2*x;
end
for i = 2:length(n)-1
    h(i+1) = 2*x*h(i)-2*(i-1)*h(i-1);
end
```

You can then call it with

```
syms x;
deg = 3;
h = Hpoly(0:deg,x)
```

which returns `[ 1, 2*x, 4*x^2 - 2, 2*x*(4*x^2 - 2) - 8*x]` (use [`expand`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/expand.html) on the output if you want). Unfortunately, this won't be much faster if `x` is symbolic.

If you're only interested in numeric results of the the polynomial evaluated at particular values, then it's best to avoid symbolic math altogether. The function above valued for double precision `x` will be three to four orders of magnitude faster than for symbolic `x`. For example:

```
x = pi;
deg = 3;
h = Hpoly(0:deg,x)
```

yields

```
h =

   1.0e+02 *

   0.010000000000000   0.062831853071796   0.374784176043574   2.103511015993210
```

**Note:**

The `hermiteH` function is R2015a+, but assuming that you still have access to the Symbolic Math toolbox and the Matlab `version` is R2012b+, you can also try calling MuPAD's [`orthpoly::hermite`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/mupad_ref/orthpoly-hermite.html). `hermiteH` used this function under the hood. See [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/calling-mupad-functions-from-matlab.html) for details on how to call MuPAD functions from Matlab. This function is a bit simpler in that it only returns a single term. Using a `for` loop:

```
syms x;
deg = 2;
h = sym(zeros(1,deg+1));
for i = 1:deg+1
    h(i) = feval(symengine,'orthpoly::hermite',i-1,x);
end
```

Alternatively, you can use [`map`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/mupad_ref/map.html) to vectorize the above:

```
deg = 2;
h = feval(symengine,'map',0:deg,'n->orthpoly::hermite(n,x)');
```

Both return `[ 1, 2*x, 4*x^2 - 2]`.

Comment: Ah, I didn't know `while` loop was slower then the `for` loop. Why is that? I didn't even think about the explicit expression, I guess that could've been a thing to try also. And I haven't even tried messing with the MuPAD yet, it's now on the list of things to looks into... For some reason, when running your code with syms x; deg = 3; h = Hpoly(0:deg,x), I'm still getting the error "Attempt to add "x" to a static workspace. Error in syms (line 83) assignin('caller', x, xsym);" Not entirely sure what that means >.> ...

Comment: It's not necessarily slower, it's just that in this case you know exactly how many iterations you need so it's a good idea to help Matlab out and specify that. `for` loops can be easier for the JIT compiler optimize in some cases (more so for numeric code than symbolic). Not sure what the cause of the error is – is that the *entire* message or does it reference a line in my code. You might also make sure you `clear all` if you're running stuff from the Command Window.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, it says `Error in test (line 17) syms x;` (`test` is the function i wrapped it all in. It only has your code and the calls). I did clear all variables. It also says "See Variables in Nested and Anonymous Functions." so maybe its not happy that everything is one function?

Comment: yep :I ... that's what it was ... how can I call it from inside the editor and not the workspace? ... bleh, it's errors like this and make absolutely no sense to and confuse the hell out of me %\

Comment: Sounds like it's because you're using `Hpoly` as a nested function rather than just a sub-function (a.k.a. [local function](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/types-of-functions.html)). There's no reason to share scope.